# Time series arrangement and operations from telemetry experiment

Tags: r

I am working with a telemetry dataset with dates (9 different days) and times. Id_tag is the id of each individual. In each row, I have the information for one individual (date time) and the distance in which It was detected

```
head(Nest5)
  id_tag        data_time distance
1     26 03/05/2016 21:35  28.9724
2     26 03/05/2016 04:39  29.6023
3     26 03/05/2016 03:58  28.9724
4     30 03/05/2016 22:14  12.5950
5     30 03/05/2016 20:09  11.9651
6     30 03/05/2016 20:12  12.5950


levels(id_tag)
 [1] "5"  "15" "20" "26" "30" "42" "44" "45" "46" "47" "54" "58" "59" "60" "61" "62" "63" "65" "66" "67"
[21] "70" "73" "82" "86"

rdate<- as.Date(Nest5$date,"%d%m%y")
#Generate a xts 

Da_w= xts(Nest5,order.by = as.POSIXct(Nest5$data_time,format="%d%m%y %H:%M"))
```

I want to rearrange my data and instead of per minutes; I want to have it in hours using the mean of distance.Additionally, I want to create an additional column with the count of times it has been register each tag in One hour

I have tried with xts function and POXixct. However, I can`t deal with my id_character, Shall I do a subset of each id and then work with xts function?Or is it a better way?

Any will be appreciated; I am already coding four days trying to solve this! =) =) =)

Thank you very much,

Best, Mara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

exp$data_time <- dmy_hm(exp$data_time)
exp$date <- format(as.POSIXct(exp$data_time,format='%m/%d/%Y'),format='%m/%d/%Y') %>% dmy()

df <- exp %>% mutate(hour = hour(data_time)) %>%
              group_by(id_tag, date, hour) %>%
              summarise(dist_mean = mean(distance),
                        count = n())
```

The result is:

```
df
  id_tag       date  hour dist_mean count
   (int)     (time) (int)     (dbl) (int)
1     26 2016-03-05     3  28.97240     1
2     26 2016-03-05     4  29.60230     1
3     26 2016-03-05    21  28.97240     1
4     30 2016-03-05    20  12.28005     2
5     30 2016-03-05    22  12.59500     1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I really apreciate it!!! it is exactly what I needed , thanks !!